# Start and stop buttons disabled in monitor tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

Start and stop buttons are disabled in monitor tomcat, 
after some 10-15 mins it is allowing me to restart the server

[image]

I am facing this issue when the tomcat stops responding and I try to restart the server, I am able to stop the server but after that it wont allow to restart the server for some amount of time. Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Most likely it's one of the applications that you're running that cause tomcat to stop responding. You'll need to debug those applications - and fix them (or it). The information you give here will not help going to the root cause of your problem. Once your application stops locking up tomcat, these problems most likely go away. Watch out for web applications that start their own threads - e.g. start doing a Thread Dump after operating your applications for a while.

Answer (score 2):

We can re-enable process in Window by Windows Task Manager.

- Open Windows Task Manager and Select process tab.
- Check show processes from all users.
- Find and select Tomcat.exe from processes tab and Click on End Process button.
  Now Open Mo-niter Tomcat.You will find buttons are enabled.